# barplot in r : increase argument font size without arguments gone missing, and plot the values near bar

Tags: r

I have almost completed a `barplot` in r. But it needs a final touch-up.

This is my code

```
HSI <- c(126,104,112,94,86)
HSI <- HSI-100
x <- barplot(HSI, main="HSI of Age", col=rainbow(10), names.arg=Category,
                           cex.names=0.2, las=1, horiz=T,axes=F, xlim=c(-50,50))
axis(1,at=seq(-50,50,10), labels = seq(50,150,10))
text(x, labels = 100+HSI, pos = 2)
```

And the graph I got is 
[image]

What I really want is similar to this picture below,
[image]

1. values viz 126,108.. should be placed correctly (next to bar).
2. The argument names are so small. I want them to clearly visible. When I try to increase size using cex.names, it won't appear in the plot.
3. Also I tried to include legend. It didn't work.
4. Also, how to decrease barplot bar's thickness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use `ggplot2`, almost everything can be altered and tuned within the graphics grammer. So for your data here:

```
HSI <- c(126,104,112,94,86)
HSI <- HSI-100
df <- data.frame(HSI=HSI, 
                 Category=c("Above Rs 1cr", "Rs 50 Lakh to Rs 1cr",
                            "Rs 30 to 50 Lakh", "Rs 20 to 30s Lakh",
                            "Rs 10 to 20 Lakh"))
```

We can use `ggplot`, to create a bar graph where you can control many of the items you have asked for:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=HSI, fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.7)) + # adjust width to change thickness
  geom_text(aes(label=HSI, y=HSI+1.1*sign(HSI)),# adjust 1.1 -  to change how far away from the final point the label is
            size=5 # adjust the size of label text           
            )+ 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

with output:

[image]

If you want more information you would have to read up on how you can change the items. Almost anything can be altered in `ggplot`.

Answer (score 3):

1. values viz 126,108.. should be placed correctly (next to bar).

You can define a vector of values for `pos` to define separate positions for each bar

2. The argument names are so small. I want them to clearly visible. When try to increase size using cex.names, it won't appear in the plot

You can use `cex` argument within the `text` call

3. Also I tried to include legend. It didn't work.

see `?legend`

4. Also, how to decrease barplot bar's thickness?

You can use the `space` argument to add space bewteen the bars

Some code

```
HSI <- c(126,104,112,94,86)
HSI <- HSI-100



x <- barplot(HSI, main="HSI of Age", col=rainbow(10), space=2, 
                                           horiz=T,axes=F, xlim=c(-50,50))

axis(1,at=seq(-50,50,10), labels = seq(50,150,10))

# add vertical line at HSI=100(0)
abline(v=0)

text(HSI, x, labels = 100+HSI, pos = c(2, 4)[(HSI>0)+1], cex=2) 

legend("topright", legend=HSI+100,  title="Mylegend", fill=rainbow(10), horiz=F)
```

Which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are four different questions. For problem 2 where the names are too small, change `cex.names` to something bigger (like 1 or 2). I cannot reproduce the problem of it not appearing in the plot, but one solution to that problem is probably to change the margins of the plot:

```
par(mar=c(3,6,3,3))
```

The second argument is the left-side margin.

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment to ask for clarification, so I have to put it here. What is the problem you have in producing a legend? I can do it just fine with, say, `legend(15,5,"legend stuff")`, but a better way, since the height of your plot is ambiguous, would be to use the built-in option `legend.text`:

```
legend.text=c("thing 1","thing 2", "thing 3", "thing 4", "thing 5")
```

Just put this as one argument to the barplot() function.

One solution to problem 1 would be to choose different numbers for the positions of the text. For instance:

```
HSITextPosition = 5*sign(HSI)+HSI
text(HSITextPosition, x, labels = 100+HSI)
```

For problem 4, you need to change the `space` option in `barplot()`, thereby adjusting the space between the bars.

Overall, you should read the documentation on the `barplot()` function or any other function you are using, because it explains much of this. Full code:

```
HSI <- c(126,104,112,94,86)
HSI <- HSI-100
HSITextPosition = 5*sign(HSI)+HSI

Category <- c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3","Group 4","Group 5")

par(mar=c(3,6,4,4))
x <- barplot(HSI, main="HSI of Age", col=rainbow(10), names.arg=Category,
         cex.names=1, las=1, horiz=T,axes=F, 
         xlim=c(-50,50),space=2,
         legend.text=c("thing 1","thing 2", "thing 3", "thing 4", "thing 5"))
axis(1,at=seq(-50,50,10), labels = seq(50,150,10))
text(HSITextPosition, x, labels = 100+HSI)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, added the plot.. dont know if you have enough rep yet. Also tweaked the `names.arg` as you had two  calls . please roll back if you dont want the edit